# Find $S_n$ summation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fractions, telescopic-series

What is the formula for $S_n$ where
$$S_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(n)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}?$$

Can we do partial fractions for solving ?

Comment: Sure, why don't you work on it a bit and show us if/ where you get stuck?

Comment: How many times same question will be asked on this site? There are many questions regarding this and many answers (mostly relying on partial fraction and telescope)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\left(\frac{1}{k+2}-\frac{1}{k+3}\right)=$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+2}\right)-\frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+3}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+3}\right)\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+3}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{1}{k+1}-\frac{1}{k+2}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+2}-\frac{1}{n+3}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n+2}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{n(n^2+6n+11)}{18(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}.$$

Comment: Simpler approach: $ = \frac{1}{3}(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(i)(i+1)(i+2)} - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(i+1)(i+2)(i+3)})$

$ = \frac{1}{3} (\frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)})$

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can do partial fractions.  Write $$\frac 1{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}=\frac an+\frac b{n+1}+\frac c{n+2}+\frac d{n+3}$$
Find $a,b,c,d$ and the sum should telescope nicely.

Comment: How to proceed?

Comment: The usual techniques work here.  You can multiply by $n$ and take the limit as $n \to 0$ to find $a$, for example.  You can clear the fractions and get a cubic in $n$ on the right, then sort out the terms for each power of $n$ to get four simultaneous equations.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align} 
{\rm S_n} &= \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(n)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}\\
 &= \frac 12 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(n^2+3n+2)-(n^2+3n)}{(n)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}\\
&=\frac 12 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(n+1)(n+2)-n(n+3)}{(n)(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}\\
&=\frac 12 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \frac{1}{n(n+3)} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} \right)\\
&=\frac 12 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n(n+3)}  -\frac 12 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} \\
&=\frac 16 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(n+3)-(n)}{n(n+3)}  -\frac 12 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(n+2)-(n+1)}{(n+1)(n+2)} \\
&=\frac 16 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac 1{n+3} \right) -\frac 12 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \frac{1}{(n+1)} - \frac 1{n+2}\right)\\
\end{align}

...telescoping?